# End expected but no clue

Tags: netlogo

It's to track the trail of a turtle and observe it but I've come to problem

Comment: Hi @manicchxld, could you please paste your code into your question instead of in an image. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the error message says 'end expected' it means you tried to start a new procedure (with `to`) without ending the previous procedure. If you have an `end` with the previous procedure, that usually means you have an error in the bracketing and NetLogo doesn't recognise the `end` as being the end of the procedure. In your case you have `ask turtles-own` instead of `ask turtles`.